# How to pass dropdown value in a form coming from a separate component

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-typescript

I have a form with two fields. One is a textfield and I cant get the data without any problem. The second field is a dropdown. This dropdown is a separate component within the form.

How can I pass the selected dropdown value with my form?

The setup is like this:

Form:

```
import { useState } from 'react';
import { SensorTypeDropdown } from '../add/SensorTypeDropdown'
const AddSensor = () => {
    const [imei, setImei] = useState('');

    const handleSubmit = (event: any) => {
        alert('Sensor with IMEI: ' + imei + ' created.');
        event.preventDefault(); //prevents page from refreshing
        setImei('')//clears form input data
    }
    return (
        <div className="container mx-auto">
            <form className="bg-white shadow-md rounded px-8 pt-6 pb-8 mb-4" onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
                <div className="mb-4">
                    <label className="block text-sm font-bold mb-2" htmlFor="imei">
                        IMEI
                    </label>
                    <input className="border rounded w-full py-2 px-3 focus:shadow-outline focus:outline-sky-700" value={imei} onChange={event => setImei(event.target.value)} id="sensorName" />
                </div>
                <div className="mb-6">
                    <label className="block text-sm font-bold mb-2" htmlFor="sensorType">
                        Sensor type
                    </label>
                    <SensorTypeDropdown/>
                </div>
                <div className="flex items-center justify-between">
                    <input type="submit" className="cursor-pointer bg-sky-700 hover:bg-sky-800 text-white font-bold py-2 px-4 rounded focus:shadow-outline" value="Create sensor" />
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    )
}

export default AddSensor;
```

And my separate dropdown component:

```
import { SharedAmbientSurrounding } from "@libs/data";
import { useState } from "react";
import { getEnumKeys } from "../../helpers/getEnumKeys";

export const  SensorTypeDropdown = () => {
  const [currentType, setCurrentType] = useState<SharedAmbientSurrounding>(SharedAmbientSurrounding.TEMPERATURE);
  const [selectedType, setSelectedType] = useState('')

  return (
    <select
      value={currentType}
      onChange={(e) => {
        setCurrentType(SharedAmbientSurrounding[e.target.value as keyof typeof SharedAmbientSurrounding]);
      }}
    >
      {getEnumKeys(SharedAmbientSurrounding).map((key, index) => (
        <option key={index} value={SharedAmbientSurrounding[key]}>
          {key}
        </option>
      ))}
    </select>
  );
}
```

Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You should manage the dropdown state in the parent component `AddSensor`

`AddSendor`

```
const AddSensor = () => {
  const [imei, setImei] = useState('');
  const [type, setType] = useState(SharedAmbientSurrounding.TEMPERATURE);

  const handleSubmit = (event) => {
    alert('Sensor with IMEI: ' + imei + ' and type: ' + type + ' created.');
    event.preventDefault(); //prevents page from refreshing
    //clears form input data
    setImei('');
    setType(SharedAmbientSurrounding.TEMPERATURE);
  }

  ....

    <div className="mb-6">
      <label className="block text-sm font-bold mb-2" htmlFor="sensorType">
        Sensor type
      </label>
      <SensorTypeDropdown value={type} onChange={setType} />
    </div>
  ...
}
```

`SensorTypeDropdown`

```
export const SensorTypeDropdown = ({value, onChange}) => {
  return (
    <select 
      value={value} 
      onChange={e => onChange(e.target.value)}
    >
      {getEnumKeys(SharedAmbientSurrounding).map((key, index) => (
        <option key={key} value={SharedAmbientSurrounding[key]}>
          {key}
        </option>
      ))}
    </select>
  );
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply! Your solution works for the most part, but I get the following error in the `AddSensor` component: `onChange is not a function`

Comment: I don't really understand why because `onChange` is not called inside `AddSensor` component. Is it a typescript error, or is it a runtime error ?